# Delphi XE and XE2 hangs when using a menu

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2

After loading a *.pas file or creating a new one, clicking on a delphi-menu or using the right mousebutton hangs Delphi. This happens in XE and XE2. I did a repair install on XE but no result. XE2 is without the updrade4. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any issues related do the problem you have. There is nothing also on the release notes of the update 4.

But i strongly recommend you to do a fresh install and always apply the latest update from Embarcadero. Also we need more information about your problem:

1 - Does this happens on other machines?

2 - What version of Windows do you use?

3 - Have you tried to uninstall all third party addons and components?

Again: uninstall all addons and components and apply the latest update. If that do not solve your issue, do a fresh install of Delphi.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do'nt use an other machine. I use windows 7 prof. It happens with XE and XE2. I did not install recently any new addons and components. I'll try to run Xe2 without any third party addons and components. Stangely it happens with Xe and XE2.

Comment: Dont you forget to also install update 4. It may solve your problem even if it is not documented.

Comment: Installed the update 4 for XE2, removed de extra addons but problem still exist. I can compile, edit, save a project, but the use of any of the menus hangs XE2. Any sugestions?